# Should I inform Business I Took my Business Elsewhere?

Tags: communication, email, customer-service

I am not sure is this an appropriate question for this forum.

I am a consumer and often email a number of businesses looking for quotes and more information about products/services that I am hoping to purchase.

Often this could involve more than one email.

Usually if I pick one supplier over another I will email them out of courtesy to say that I have gone to another supplier --- if anything just so they don't waste time following up.

Is this good behaviour or closer to rude and obnoxious?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the workplace, but about the relationship between customer and business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information is valuable, generally you don't give it away without seeing some advantage to yourself in doing so. So best option is just to go with the one you chose and leave the rest hanging. You never know they might chase you with a better deal.

What you are doing is helpful to the business, but unnecessary and free.

Answer (score 5):

As someone in a very competitive industry, getting feedback without having to chase it is very helpful.

It's especially so if the person who took the business elsewhere tells me why they did IE price, delivery time, prefer a different manufacturer to the one I offered.

This is very useful information to me for future quotations with this customer since it means I can check their feedback and perhaps offer something different to give myself a better chance of securing their next order.

You can of course say that you went elsewhere with no additional information, but if the suppliers you are using don't know why they didn't get your business, they don't know how to make an offer that might benefit you next time.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider it rude, more as helpful - as you said, they won't need to waste their time selling if you already bought somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's kept clear and polite I think that only easily offended people would find it rude.

You can be sure the supplier won't like it , it's never pleasent to loose (or don't get) a client , but there's a low chance they find it rude.

I don't know if it's good behaviour or just something you do to feel better about it but to me it's neither rude or obnoxious.